# My output will not write to a file

Tags: c++, file

Here is the code i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    float x;//the data value
    float sum=0.0;//the running total of the values readd
    int n=0;//the number of data values read
    float cube;

  FILE* fin = fopen("sumcubes.in", "r"); /* open for reading */
FILE* fout=fopen("sumcubes.c","w");

while(1){
    fscanf(fin,"%f",&x);
    if(feof(fin))break;
    n++;
    cube=x*x*x;
    sum=sum+cube;

}

fprintf(fout,"There are %d values in the file:",n);
fprintf(fout,"The sum of cubes of these values is:%f",sum);
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
system("sumcubes.in");
system("sumcubes.c");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it would read the values in the file and then cube each value. after cubing each value in file it will get the sum of these cube values. however nothing was printed to the output.

Comment: Was the file created?  You should check the result of fopen() to verify that it succeeded.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect to execute two files, via the `system()` library call, that do not actually contain an executable program, but rather a list of numbers?

Comment: step through the code with a debugger

Comment: Assuming `int main(void\n` is just a typo, please check the values of `fin` and `fout`, and also `errno` if the values are `NULL`. I suspect you need to ensure that the input file is in the correct directory.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to add '\n' at the end of each of those print strings.  Not that that seems to be germane to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran your code (after Ken Y-N fixed the typo), it worked just fine, except that the three system() calls generated "command not found" error messages. The file sumcubes.c contained the expected results, though why you would give that file a .c extension baffles me. Perhaps the file sumcubes.in is not in your current directory when you are running the executable? When I tried that, I got a segmentation fault, but since you don't check the results of fopen(), if the input file does not exist (or is not in your current directory), anything could happen.